# Are the contens of a json file viewable to the public on a web server?

Tags: javascript, json

Like the contents (code) of a php file gets converted to HTML when viewing a webpage source, does the same apply to a json file or is it like javascript and HTML where anyone can view its source code?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone that can look at the source can end up finding the json data. It is a plain string representing an object